# 1960s British SF TV episode - Fantasy Dream

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember an episode of a TV series, I guess late 60s/early 70s.
The protagonist (I think a writer) seems to have spells where he becomes some kind of SF/Fantasy warrior in an alien or future world. I vaguely remember plastic armour and a sword or ray pistol.
It could be that the setting is from one of his own books.
If I remember correctly the point was whether it was real or an hallucination.

Anybody know the name, series, and whether it was based on a book?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!
"Get Off My Cloud", from Out of the Unkown.

Comment: That's great! Could you also write _how_ you found it, and how you determined it was the episode you were looking for? This will help future askers. Also, you should be able to accept your answer in 48 hours by clicking the check mark near it.

Comment: I knew it must be one of a few 70s, 80s UK series. Via Wikipedia, I found www.625.org.uk which has an Out of the Unknown episode archive. Unfortunately no recording of the episode exists, but a boxed DVD set of the extant episodes is available very cheaply.

Comment: You can click the check mark to the left to accept you answer ;)